# How to retain password on reactivating users in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I will explain my scenario step by step so that it will be easy for you guys to understand the issue properly

```
   1) Im working on a portlet that creates users in to a Ldap server programatically
    2) Liferay is configured with LDAP server with the import option enabled so the groups and users are imported to liferay 
    3) The users and groups are listed in the control panel of Liferay
    4) I tried to login with those users and Login was successfull!!!
    5) Now i delete the user from my portlet
```

I use the following method for activate/deactivate user

```
 public static void activateDeactiavteLportalUser(String  email,boolean status )
    {
        Company company;
        try
        {
            company = CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByMx(PropsUtil.get(PropsKeys.COMPANY_DEFAULT_WEB_ID));
            long companyID = company.getCompanyId();
            User liferayuser=   UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress( companyID, email );
               if(status)
               {
                   UserLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus(liferayuser.getUserId() , WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED);
               }
               else
               {
                   UserLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus(liferayuser.getUserId() , WorkflowConstants.STATUS_INACTIVE);
               }




        }
        catch ( PortalException | SystemException e )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Now in to my problem. When i deactivate a user the password field becomes empty and i saw the user_ table of liferay has updated the column PasswordReset to 1.
Now im not able to login with that user. Is it possible to prevent the password from updating? Or should i use the actual delete user method for user deletion?

Liferay thread : https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/56382345